# Error: cannot find symbol- variable. Refering to ".length"

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, replace

Im trying to make every "*ADJEKTIVER*" strings in the *storyList* array into random strings from my *adjectivesList* array. When I'm trying to compile, I only get the error: *cannot find symbol- variable*. With .*length* as the variable/attribute. Been searching for a solution quite a while now

```
    ArrayList<String> storyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    storyList = reader.getWordsInFile(storyFilename);

    ArrayList<String> adjectivesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    adjectivesList = reader.getWordsInFile(adjectivesFilename);

    for (int index =0; index < storyList.length; index++)
    {
        storyList[index] = storyList[index].replace("ADJEKTIV", adjectivesList[random.nextInt(adjectivesList)]);
    }

    writer.write(adjectivesList, outputFilename);
```

Comment: *Lists* have *size()*. Arrays have *length*. Strings have *length()*. Please don't ask me why they aren't consistent :(

Answer (score 1):

use `storyList.size()` method instead of `storyList.length`

```
for (int index =0; index < storyList.size(); index++)
```

Comment: @Mr.Robot - Nope. This answers the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

`Arralist` or `List` doesnt have any property named "length". use `size()` method instead

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a public final int property called length, that holds the number of elements in the array, arrays can't change how many elements they have in Java. 
Which brings me to ArrayList having a collection that can change the number of elements it has is useful, but it's not magic(I would've liked someone to tell me this). It has an Array of type E[] I will call this internal array arr.
When you push an element to an ArrarList

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    E[] temp = new E[this.arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++)
        temp[i] = this.arr[i];

    this.arr = new E[this.arr.length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++)
        this.arr[i] = (i == temp.length ? e : temp[i]);

    temp = null; // free temp or let it fall out of scope
    return true;
}

// Removing is easy too

public E remove(int index) { // I'm just doing the first of the overloaded methods, in api
    E returnValue = this.arr[index];
    E[] temp = new E[this.arr.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++)
        if (i != index) temp[i] = this.arr[i];

    this.arr = new E[this.arr.length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++)
        this.arr[i] = (i == temp.length ? e : temp[i]);

    temp = null; // free temp or let it fall out of scope
    return returnValue;
}
```

The being able to change the length forces it to be accessed in a dynamic way in Java via a method called size in this case.

```
public int size() {
    return this.arr.length;
}
```

Java exists both as a standard and as an implementation, the former might be implemented such that Strings are mutable so making String have a length method makes code more compatible between the implementations of the standard, as implementations(not necessarily those of Java) have been known to deviate, so making them more compatible makes sense for the Java devs.

As for why ArrayList uses size() as the method name, while String uses length(), and Array uses length, I don't know although in my opinion(warning opinions ahead) it's not unreasonable that accessing the lengths got implemented the way they did, and the Java devs felt locked in, because changing the spec would also required changing the code in question.

```
public int length() {
    return this.arr.length;
}
```

All code shown is merely for demonstration purposes, and comes as is, and is without warranty of any kind.